# Get newly typed values only in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following state from my app:

```js
  const [education, setEducation] = useState([
    {
      institution: "University",
      area: "President",
      studyType: "Bachelor",
      startDate: "2013-01-01",
      endDate: "2014-01-01",
      gpa: "4.0",
      highlights: ["DB1101 - Basic SQL"]
    },
  ]);
```

And a method to update the state:

```js
  const onCoursesChange = (event, index) => {
    const list = [...education];
    const {value} = event.target;
    list[index].highlights.push(value);
    setEducation((prev) => list);
    console.log(education[index].courses);
  };
```

And I have displayed all the values in the input field like this:

```js
  <Input
    type="text"
    label="Courses"
    name="courses"
    value={item.highlights.toString()}
    changed={(event) => {
      onCoursesChange(event, index);
    }}
  />
```

The two way binding is working but whenever I type something the new text is joined with old value and pushed to state. Below is the console.log output

> ["DB1101 - Basic SQL", "DB1101 - Basic SQLa"]

I know this is caused by `value={item.highlights.toString()}` in the input. How do i get the newly typed values only ?

Is it doable ? Or is there any other better approach ?

Comment: Do you want to store multiple values in `highlights`?

Comment: Try replace list[index].highlights.push(value) with list[index].highlights = [value, ...list[index].highlights];

Comment: @Nithish yes in this ["course1", "course2", "course3"]

Comment: @huanfeng tried it. It is also doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is working like this:

You have an array of strings (`highlights`) and you pass the stringified version of this array to the input's value (in your case the `toString` produces `"DB1101 - Basic SQL"`)

When you type in a character it get's appended to the original value (like you wrote `"DB1101 - Basic SQLa"`), and so this string gets pushed into the highlights array, which results in  `["DB1101 - Basic SQL", "DB1101 - Basic SQLa"]`

The answer here depends on how you want this to work, I present you one possible solution:

Display an input field for every item in `highlight` and have a button to add a new highlight (push an empty string in the array).

```
{item.highlights.map((highlight, highlightIndex) => (
  <Input
    type="text"
    label="Courses"
    name="courses"
    value={highlight}
    changed={(event) => {
      onCoursesChange(event, index, highlightIndex);
    }}
  />
))}
```

`onChange` handler:

```
const onCoursesChange = (event, index, highlightIndex) => {
  const newEducation = {
    ...education[index],
    highlights: Object.assign([], education[index].highlights, {highlightIndex: event.target.value})
  };
  
    
  setEducation(Object.assign([], education, {index: newEducation}));
};
```

And then somewhere you place a button to add a new highlight for the education, with an empty string:

```
// index is the education's index
const addHighlight = (index) => {
  const newEducation = {
    ...education[index],
    highlights: [...education[index].highlights, '']
  };

  setEducation(Object.assign([], education, {index: newEducation}));
};

// index is the education's index
<button onClick={() => addHighlight(index)}>Add highlight</button>
```

Also you can add a button for every highlight row, to delete the corresponding highlight from the education (by index).

Comment: Yes. I have followed similar approach for may other component. Just wanted to try new method. And course field won't receive any long inputs so.

Comment: If you want to push a new item to an array it wouldn't work with onChange as it will push a new item for every keystroke. Maybe you would wan't to push the new to the highlights on pressing the return key and then empty out the field, so you can add new items to the highlight.